# I can't find exim on the latest cygwin installation

Tags: cygwin, exim

I can't find exim on the latest cygwin installation (1.7.29). Was it removed? How can I install it in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is notorious with its silent disappearing packages. According to the cygwi package search ( http://cygwin.com/packages/ ) , there isn't really an exim package in the 64-bit cygwin.

But in the 32-bit, it exists.

A second maybe cause of the problem, that you use an incomplete cygwin mirror. There is many of them. On the begin of the cygwin setup, you could try simply another mirror. But this will only work if you have a 32 bit version.

---

The ultimate solution for your problem were if you recompiled exim from scratch, and this is what I did in your place.

Answer (score 0):

According to my quick searches of the cygwin apps mailing list, the exim package is currently available for 32 bit cygwin, but is currently missing in the 64 bit cygwin.  I am not a cygwin developer, but it seems like there is a problem building exim in the 64 bit cygwin environment.

According to the search page at http://www.cygwin.com/packages/, the x86 version can be downloaded from http://cygwin.com/packages/x86/exim/, but there is no x86_64 version listed.

Answer (score 0):

The 64 bit package of Exim has been uploaded to the Cygwin site on 2015-01-26.